# Nested Forms Rails 4.0 Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Been trying this all night and I can't get the photo upload to work. The 2 tables work just fine but no dice on a polymorphic table that holds photos. Any fresh new eyes would be such great help.

```
def restaurant_params
    params.require(:restaurant).permit(:res_name, :res_description, restaurant_branches_attributes: [ :id, :address_line1, :address_line2, :address_line3, :address_line4, :address_line5, :address_line6, :number_phone, :number_fax, :email, :_destroy ], pictures_attributes: [ :id, :name, :image] )
end

class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

end

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :restaurant_branches
accepts_nested_attributes_for :restaurant_branches, allow_destroy: true
```

end

```
class RestaurantBranch < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :restaurants 
has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true
before_save :set_address

def set_contact_info
    contact_info = "Phone: #{self[:number_phone]} Fax: #{self[:number_fax]} Email: #{self[:email]}"
end

def set_address
    address = self.address_line2.nil? ? partial_address.titleize : complete_address.titleize
end

private 

def complete_address
    address = "#{self[:address_line1]} #{self[:address_line2]} #{self[:address_line3]} #{self[:address_line4]} #{self[:address_line5]} #{self[:address_line6]}"
end

def partial_address
    address = "#{self[:address_line1]} #{self[:address_line3]} #{self[:address_line4]} #{self[:address_line5]} #{self[:address_line6]}"
end
```

end

Comment: pictures_attributes is defined in RestaurantBranch model, but in the permit, you are declaring pictures_attributes at the Restaurant level and not at the RestaurantBranch level. Are you sure that the permit declaration is sematically correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multi-Level Association**

The polymorphic nature of the associations *shouldn't* be a problem, as Rails will typically send the data to the `association` - in this case `pictures`

I think your problem is more to do with the multi-level association you have, specifically that you need to pass the attributes as follows `[form submit] > RestaurantBranch > Pictures`

--

We've done this before, and here's how you do it:

```
#app/controllers/restaurants_controller.rb
Class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @restaurant = Resaurant.new
       @restaurant.restaurant_branches.build.pictures.build #-> notice multi-level nesting
   end

   def create
       @restaurant = Restaurant.new(restaurant_params)
       @restaurant.save
   end

   private

   def restaurant_params
        params.require(:restaurant).permit(:res_name, :res_description, restaurant_branches_attributes: [ :id, :address_line1, :address_line2, :address_line3, :address_line4, :address_line5, :address_line6, :number_phone, :number_fax, :email, :_destroy,  pictures_attributes: [ :id, :name, :image]])
   end
end

#app/views/restaurants/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @restaurant do |f| %>
     <%= f.fields_for :restaurant_branches do |rb| %>
         <%= rb.fields_for :pictures do |p| %>
             <%= p.file_field :image %>
         <% end %>
     <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks! i knew it was going to be written in like an array in array method.